# Default check a checkbox html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a checkbox checked by default, but everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it has to do with the PHP that is in the code.

```
function show_subscription_checkbox ($id='0') {
    global $sg_subscribe;
    sg_subscribe_start();

    if ( $sg_subscribe->checkbox_shown ) return $id;
    if ( !$email = $sg_subscribe->current_viewer_subscription_status() ) :
        $checked_status = ( !empty($_COOKIE['subscribe_checkbox_'.COOKIEHASH]) && 'checked' == $_COOKIE['subscribe_checkbox_'.COOKIEHASH] ) ? true : false;
    ?>   
<p <?php if ($sg_subscribe->clear_both) echo 'style="clear: both;" '; ?>class="subscribe-to-comments">
        <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" id="subscribe" value="subscribe" style="width: auto;" <?php if ( $checked_status ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/>

        <label for="subscribe"><?php echo $sg_subscribe->not_subscribed_text; ?></label>
        </p>
```

This is a wordpress plugin that allows you to subscribe to blog comments.

I have tried

```
echo 'checked=\"checked\" ';
echo 'checked="checked" ' ;
echo 'checked> ';
```

The plugin author states that you used to be able to default check the checkbox but not anymore.

Answer (score 30):

Since this is showing up in google for "default checked checkbox", I figured I'd answer it. Alpay was right: The correct way to ensure that a checkbox is checked by default is like so (followed by an example of one that is not checked):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car    
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike
```

Answer was found on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp). The author of the original question was having trouble with his PHP code, which is not at all related to the question title.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML, if you want a checkbox to be checked by default, see the following;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="uc"> This checkbox is unchecked <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" value="c" checked> This checkbox is checked<br>
```

So, you might consider changing

```
<?php if ( $checked_status ) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ( $checked_status ) echo 'checked'; ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `$checked_status = ( !empty($_COOKIE['subscribe_checkbox_'.COOKIEHASH]) && 'checked' == $_COOKIE['subscribe_checkbox_'.COOKIEHASH] ) ? true : false;` line executes before the html is parsed?

Comment: is that w3c compliant? not sure

Comment: @Alpay I copied the code straight from the plugin file. The author said you used to be able to have the box default checked, but that's not an option anymore?. But I figure there has to be a way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the HTML markup being generated; `echo 'checked="checked" '`, as in the question, works well, and so would the simpler `echo 'checked'`.

The problem is with the condition `$checked_status`. You are testing for a variable that is undefined, as far as the code posted is considered.

Comment: I guess I should of posted the code that is above what I posted initially. I have updated my post with more code.

Comment: You have now added code that tests for a cookie being set. There is no indication of where it might actually be set.

Comment: Hmm. This is getting a little over my head. As far as I can tell that is the only code associated with the checkbox. Is there a way to share the whole file? Besides copying and pasting all the code? I may have left something out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I figured out that I was trying to put the checkbox into a table but left out the and.

didn't check:

```
if(!$stump){echo '<input type="checkbox" name="stump" value="stump" checked="checked"><b> Stump Job!</b>';}
```

checked:

```
if(!$stump){echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="stump" value="stump" checked="checked"><b> Stump Job!</b></td>';}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regular PHP you can use this to "save" the checked state after its been submitted.

```
<form name="checkbox" method="post" action="#" >
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Bike" <?php if ($_POST['checkbox1']=="Bike") echo "checked";?>>I have a bike
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="Car" <?php if ($_POST['checkbox2']=="Car") echo "checked";?>>I have a car 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Display this Data" />
```

if you want to use this data for something else after the submit, just add:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['checkbox1']) OR isset($_POST['checkbox2']) ) 
   {
    echo "for 1 : ".$_POST['checkbox1']."for 2: ".$_POST['checkbox2'];
   }
?>
```

if you want to clear the form (basically clear all the post data) you can add:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type="submit" name="Clear all form data" value= "Clear this form">
</form>
```